# Regarding electronic item to carry

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, cellphones

I want to take 2 iPhones with me (36000 INR each) to India from USA,as i stayed 4 month here and I am resident of INDIA and went US for official work.
Will there be any problem or any amount do i need to pay to custom or any where else in US/INDIA airport?

I am already carrying my used Camera(40000 INR+Professional laptop) with me.

ITEMS carry  :: 1 Lpatop(offical)+DSLR camera(not from US ,already had of 40000 INR+ 2 new iPHONEs of 36000+36000 brought from US and carrying to india)

Note : I am travelling alone.

Regards,
Anshuman Gaur